# How can I display text in the center of an image in a Bixby result view?

Tags: bixby

I currently have a result view set up to display text on top of an image. I have an `image-card` and a `title-area` that displays text on the image. I can specify the `halign (Center)` option to get it to show up in the middle on the horizontal axis (so i have it halfway between the left and right sides), but it appears pulled to the bottom of the image. Is there a way to center it along the vertical axis or put space underneath to raise it up?

Here is the image card:

```
image-card {
  aspect-ratio (21:9)
  image-url ("https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket/path/to/image.png")
  title-area {
    halign (Center)
    slot1 {
      if (exists(result.Value)){
        text {
          style (Title_XXL)
          value ("#{value(result.Value)}")
        }
      } else {
        text {
          style (Title_XXL)
          value ("No Data")
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Below are samples of what i am hoping to achieve with the text within an image card

[image: What I have]
[image: What I want]

Comment: Can you attach a screen shot of the current display and the intended display?

Comment: Just updated it with an example i made in google slides!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not currently supported. Any component that does let you control the vertical axis will have a `valign` key.

Comment: FYI: Here is the Feature Request link: https://support.bixbydevelopers.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/360000183273-Feature-Requests. This forum is open to other Bixby developers who can upvote it, leading to more visibility within the community and with the Product Management team.